# render text into Grayscale?

Tags: c#, .net

using(C# .NET) Is it possible to render text into Grayscale. Let me explain little briefly, when a user types text in 'textBox' the text has to get displayed on the same window as Grayscale. "AND IT HAS TO GET DONE IN Windows7 and later it'll get installed on Windows Server 2008" So any HELP please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase?

Comment: You mean instead of ClearType?

Comment: Do try to use the common meaning of "grayscale".  Look it up in a dictionary if necessary.  Text has a color, not a range of gray color values.

Answer (score 2):

For WinForms (.NET 2.0) you wanna set the ForeColor property (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez1ywchy.aspx)):

```
MyTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
```

For WPF (.NET 3.0 and up) you wanna set the ForeGround property (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground.aspx))

```
MyTextBox.ForeGround = Brushes.Gray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) Inside the delegate for the TextField.TextChanged put this:

```
If (sender.Text == "textBox")
{ 
    sender.ForeColor = Color.Gray 
} 
else
{
    sender.ForeColor = Color.Black
}
```